# Why is there a line in the center of freelensing photos taken with a Canon 5D mkIII?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iii, freelensing

I have been doing a day of free-lensing shooting with a Canon 5D mkIII, and on both my photos and videos, there is a perfectly vertical line splitting the picture into two parts, with a small exposure difference between the two parts.

It is subtle on photos but quite visible in video, with the movement and this line still remaining.

Has anyone have ever faced the same problem? How can I correct it?

FYI: I have been using Canon EF 70-200mm f2.8 L IS and Canon 50mm f1.4 USM both with ND filters.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Hmm, I've got nothing other than the observation there are actually multiple bands of different sizes.

Comment: The other bands are flares created by the free lensing, only the vertical band bother me.

Comment: I'm talking about other vertical bands.  There are actually three vertical bands on the first image of various widths and atleast one larger one if not two on the second.

Comment: I'm currently uploading an example on vimeo, this way it will be easier to visualize the problem.

Comment: I setup a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14216/discussion-for-line-appearing-in-the-center-of-freelensing-photos-with-5d-mkiii) for talking about this in more detail.

Comment: It is all various types of lens flare. This is quite common when free-lensing unless you create some sort of enclosure to prevent light from entering between the lens and camera.

Comment: I don't know which direction the 5D iii reads from the sensor, but that looks like tearing to me. See if you can reproduce this with both the lens and camera clamped down somewhere solid.

Comment: I am gonna try to upload an other example today. I can't try it anymore it was rental equipment. (sorry to post here and not in the chat room but I don't have enough 'rep' to rejoin the room)

Comment: I just added an other video in the question, I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the photos what is occurring but if it is happening with two different lenses then it clearly is the camera.  If it is is in exactly the same place and same size and geometry with both lenses then it is internal to the camera circuitry.   If it is exactly the same then it is your image sensor.  It might be as simple as cleaning it but take a look at it with the mirror up and see if you can see any smears or defects in the sensor or its surface.